# Can I use same signing certificate with knife ec2 that I use with ec2-api-tools

Tags: authentication, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, knife, ec2-api-tools

I have created a self-signed certificate and added it as 'signing certificate' on my AWS account. It works with ec2-api-tools with no problem.

Can I use it with the knife-ec2 plugin as well? How?
If not, what is the best way to authenticate knife-ec2?

Answer (score 0):

No, knife-ec2 only supports key/secret authentication.